# Increase 50% vs Increase BY 50%

Tags: prepositions

I was wondering whether "by" should be inserted between "increased" and "more than 50%" in the below sentence. When googling, "increased 50%" appears almost as frequently as "increased by 50%." But I can see only "increased by 50%" in dictionaries' examples. I would like to know which is correct. The below comes at around 0:04 in the CBS News clip, https://archive.org/download/KPIX_20220831_013000_CBS_Evening_News_With_Norah_ODonnell/KPIX_20220831_013000_CBS_Evening_News_With_Norah_ODonnell.mp4?t=960/1020&ignore=x.mp4

> And as the number of women in construction has increased (by) more
> than 50% in a decade to more than a million, it's in part because of
> recruitment campaigns like this one.

Answer (score 4):

Entities increase/decrease **by** a percentage but, as the Ngram graph shows, the preposition is commonly omitted. It's interesting to note, however, that the number of omissions has fallen steadily since the 1980s.

While the construction is clearly understood either way, to be correct, best include the preposition.

So you might have, depending on the construction **an increase OF  /  an increase BY / an increase TO** or you might just see the preposition omitted after the verb.

https://tinyurl.com/4xzbwu4r

Comment: In your second NGram, you're comparing nouns to verbs. All the "increase of" examples are nouns, and all the "increase by" examples are verbs. You can show this by [adding "an" in front](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+increase+of+50%25%2Can+increase+by+50%25&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3). The "of" curve keeps the same shape, while the "by" curve disappears.

Comment: @gotube My slip. Noted and corrected (Would have been corrected earlier but for a mega storm playing havoc with the electrics.)

Comment: You're still comparing nouns to verbs. All the hits in "**an** increase of 50%" are nouns, while all the hits in "increase by 50%" are verbs. The OP didn't ask about "of" or nouns, so I don't see how the "of" info contributes to the answer, rather than just confusing it

Answer (score 3):

Both of them will work. It depends on the context. Usually people will just pick the one that sounds best in the context it is given in.

Comment: Just to add to this, even the unit percentage is subjective. For example, if I change the volume from 10 to 60 (out of 100 max), did I increase it by 50% (i.e. I added 50 out of the total 100) or did I increase it by 500% (since 10 x 6 = 60)? Both are correct, but they use a different unit percentage (the former expresses the percentage relative to the total of 100, whereas the latter expresses the percentage relative to the 10).

Comment: @Flater: "50%" could only mean half the potential volume if the volumes are already being expressed in percent (e.g. "I change the volume from 10%" and not "from 10 out of 100") but in that case it does indeed lead to ambiguity.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I suspected beforehand that picking 100 as the total volume would redirect people to think of the number as a percentage, but I decided to keep it because of the simpler maths. Change the total volume to, let's say, 120 (and adjust the other numbers accordingly) and the core of my points still stands.

Comment: @Flater You unambiguously increase the volume by 500 percent, and by 50 [percentage points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage_point). An "increase" is not in comparison to a potential max value, but to an actual value.

Comment: @Flater I have read it, about one day before you told me to. 50/120 ≈ 41,7 percentage points, obviously. Which is still an increase by 500 percent. Feel free to read the wiki article.